# '<uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>' at maven 3

Tags: maven, repository

Why maven 3 depreciated false at Snapshot repository configuration at pom.xml? What is the motivation behind it?

```
  <snapshotRepository>
     <id>snapshots</id>
     <url>http://nexus.mycompany.local/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
     <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
  </snapshotRepository>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As answered in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739566/maven-3-and-timestamps), the comments in [this nexus bug](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-4534) says why uniqueVersion was present in the first place and why it is not available in maven3. Quoting from it,

> It's not recommended to use non-unique snapshots since they lead to
>   non-reproducible builds. The main use case for these was to save disk
>   space in the repository, but this is best handled by scheduling a
>   periodic snapshot removal task to keep the number of versions down

.