# Maven 3 and timestamps

Tags: maven, timestamp, maven-3, nexus

I have various questions regarding Maven 3 and Nexus repository. At our nexus repository I would like to resolve only timestamp dependencies. That is to say I would like to prevent downloading timestapped dependencies to my local repository. And also at my nexus configuration having only latest snapshot jar for a version is totally fine.

My question is regarding timestamped dependencies at nexus and local repository.

1. Is having only latest Snapshot at repository a good practice? Why or why not?
2. I have done at my plugin management section of the parent pom of the deploy plugin `<uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>` but at hudson I still continue to see timestamps at jar like this `bundle-service-client-1.0-20110209.145744-25`
3. I have came across a comment at another question,

> The timestamped artifacts should never be see inside your local
>   (~/.m2/repository) repository. If they are, something is wrong.

Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting from the relevant section in [Maven 3.x Compatibility Notes](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x+Compatibility+Notes#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-NonuniqueSnapshotDeployments)

> The setting false for a distribution
>   repository has no effect in version 3.x, snapshot artifacts will
>   always be deployed using a timestamped version.

Also, look at the comments in [this nexus jira bug](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-4534) on a nice explanation to your other questions.

Comment: I am aware of reproducible builds but your answer is not addressing my questions. I have done unique version at the deploy plugin. Thanks

Comment: Maven 3 no longer supports this feature, by design. It always generates unique version numbers on deployment.