# Maven: How to deploy with same file name of same version

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, maven-deploy-plugin

When I run maven deploy, of version example: 0.0.1 SNAPSHOT,
then it automatically add version + timestamp.
How to remove this and do deploy.
I need only app.jar or app-0.0.1 SNAPSHOT.jar not with timestamp
[Refer image Snapshot of artifactory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOArm.jpg)

Comment: SNAPSHOTs need the timestamp to find out which is newest.  Releases don't.

Comment: Outside of your repository manager you reference them as `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` so you usually get the newest one and you can't change the naming schema which is inside repository managers..Where do you need the name like you suggested? Inside Jenkins?

Comment: so if i use release then it wont have timestamp is it ?

Answer (score 1):

Nexus and Artifactory store Snapshot artifacts with a timestamp in the version. This timestamp can also be used to directly address a concrete artifact (though this is not recommended in most cases).

I see no reason why you want to change the handling of Snapshots inside Nexus/Artifactory and it is probably not possible.

It is possible, though, to strip the version in various situations where you *use* an artifact as dependency, e.g. when building an ear or war.

Answer (score -1):

Use `-DuniqueVersion=false` parameter when you're creating the build.
Refer [Link](http://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-deploy-plugin-2.6/examples/disabling-timestamps-suffix.html) .

Comment: Not available in Maven 3, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7739898/927493.