# Is there any way to change the Nexus URL path during artifact upload in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, deployment, jenkins-pipeline, nexus, artifacts

I'm trying to upload the artifact into nexus using Jenkins pipeline, in which the overall pipeline ends at last stage. where the artifact is not get uploading into the nexus repository.

Say example:
http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases is my existing repository and that am trying to upload the artifact into it. But when i kick off the Jenkins pipeline build am seeing the url reaches to:
 http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/repository/releases.
I'm quite confused where the "repository" comes from into the above url.

I tried to edit the url so many times but still getting same issue

Uploading artifact blt-server.war started....

GroupId: null

ArtifactId: blt-server

Classifier:

Type: war

Version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

File: blt-server.war

Repository:releases

Downloading: http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/repository/releases/maven-metadata.xml

Uploading: http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/repository/releases/blt-server/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/blt-server-0.0.1-20190906.152523-1.war

10 % completed (5.5 MB / 55 MB).

20 % completed (11 MB / 55 MB).

30 % completed (17 MB / 55 MB).

40 % completed (22 MB / 55 MB).

50 % completed (28 MB / 55 MB).

60 % completed (33 MB / 55 MB).

70 % completed (39 MB / 55 MB).

80 % completed (44 MB / 55 MB).

90 % completed (50 MB / 55 MB).

100 % completed (55 MB / 55 MB).

Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact :blt-server:war:0.0.1-20190906.152523-1 in releases (http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/repository/releases)

Uploading file blt-server.war failed.

I expect the url should be like this:
http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases while uploading the war file, but it's not.

Here is my pipeline script:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label "master"
    }
    tools {
    maven "Maven-3.5.2" 
 }
 environment {
     NEXUS_VERSION = "nexus3"
     NEXUS_PROTOCOL = "http"
     NEXUS_URL = "localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories"
     NEXUS_REPOSITORIES = "releases"
     NEXUS_CREDENTIAL_ID = "SonatypeREMNexus3"
     CREDENTIALSID= "********confidential***"
 }
 stages {
     stage("clone bitbucket") {
         steps { 
             checkout(
        [
            $class: 'GitSCM', 
            branches: [[name: 'master']], 
            doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
            extensions: [
                [$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', relativeTargetDir: 'build'] 
            ], 
            submoduleCfg: [], 
            userRemoteConfigs: [
                [
                    credentialsId: '********confidential***',
                    url: 'ssh://git@bitbucket.confidential:7999/blt/blt-server.git'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    )

             }
     }
     stage('Build & Test') {
         steps {
             script {
        withMaven(
            options: [artifactsPublisher(disabled: true)],
            jdk: 'JAVA-1.8.0_152',
            maven: 'Maven-3.5.2') {
            sh "mvn clean package -f build/pom.xml"
        }
     }
    }
     }
     stage("publish to nexus") {
         steps {
             script {
             pom = readMavenPom file: "build/pom.xml";
             filesByGlob = findFiles(glob: "build/target/*.${pom.packaging}");
             echo "${filesByGlob[0].name} ${filesByGlob[0].path} ${filesByGlob[0].directory} ${filesByGlob[0].length} ${filesByGlob[0].lastModified}"
             artifactPath = filesByGlob[0].path;
             artifactExists = fileExists artifactPath;
             if(artifactExists) {
                 echo "*** File: ${artifactPath}, group: ${pom.groupId}, packaging: ${pom.packaging}, version: ${pom.version}"
                 nexusArtifactUploader(
                 nexusVersion: NEXUS_VERSION,
                 protocol: NEXUS_PROTOCOL,
                 nexusUrl: NEXUS_URL,
                 groupId: pom.groupId,
                 version: pom.version,
                 repository: NEXUS_REPOSITORIES,
                 credentialsId: NEXUS_CREDENTIAL_ID,
                 artifacts: [
                     [artifactId: pom.artifactId,
                     classifier: '',
                     file: artifactPath,
                     type: pom.packaging],
                     [artifactId: pom.artifactId,
                     classifier: '',
                     file: "build/pom.xml",
                     type: "pom"]
                ]
            );
                 } else {
                     error "*** File: ${artifactPath}, could not be found";
                 }

             }
         }
     }
     }

 }
```

Comment: Why is your groupid "null"? Maven will.upload to coords.based on GAV. What repositories (and of what type) have you defined in Nexus?

Comment: Without having provided a sample code of what you use in your pipeline and where you have tried editing the URL, it is difficult to tell where the problem lies. The repository URL might have been specified either in your project `pom.xml` or in `~/.m2/settings.xml` on your build agent. If your project doesn’t use a `pom.xml`, the repository URL could even be a part of the `mvn deploy` command as the option `-Durl` or if you use `nexusArtifactUploader`, it could be specified as `nexusUrl`. Many possibilities!

Comment: @Dibakar Aditya Thanks for the quick look.
I've uploaded my pipeline code above. please check out.

Comment: @IanW Thanks for the quick check. Regarding "groupid" null i'm not sure why its showing it as "null" I verified the pom.xml  in which it has like this:
```
 <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

Comment: @nk07 Thanks for sharing additional details. This makes troubleshooting easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
NEXUS_VERSION = "nexus3"
NEXUS_PROTOCOL = "http"
NEXUS_URL = "localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories"
```

The Nexus version specified is Nexus 3 but the URL follows Nexus 2 format.

Nexus 3 uses the URL format `/repository/<repo-id>/<path-of-file>` whereas, Nexus 2 uses `/content/repositories/<repo-id>/<path-of-file>`.

If you are on Nexus 2, just update the version `NEXUS_VERSION = "nexus2"`.

If on Nexus 3:

1. Upgrade the [Nexus Artifact Uploader plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Nexus+Artifact+Uploader) to version 2.6 or higher.
2. Replace `localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories` with `localhost:8081/nexus` or `localhost:8081`, as applicable to your Nexus repository.

You can also [configure Nexus 3 to use legacy URL paths](https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Upgrade+Procedures#UpgradeProcedures-ConfiguringLegacyURLPaths).

Comment: That was excellent and quick one!
It works fantastic.. kudos to you!!! @Dibakar Aditya

Comment: @nk07 Thanks! Glad that I could help. You can choose to mark this as the accepted answer so that others facing a similar problem might find this helpful too.

Comment: And one quick thing please, the deployed war and snapshot in nexus having the date/timestamps. I'm trying to disable it and i need the file name looks like demo-0.0.1.war. I've tried to disable it using uniqueVersion: false but no luck on it.
Could you please tell me whats the mistake that i'm doing?
@Dibakar Aditya

Comment: I am afraid, this plugin doesn't support non-unique versions. In fact, the support is even removed in Maven 3, if you wish to deploy using `mvn`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. By any chance alternative way to remove the timestamp from the artifact file? currently i'm seeing all the file names like:
Parent Directory
```
demo-server-0.0.1-20190909.162347-1.war   
demo-server-0.0.1-20190909.162347-1.war.md5   
demo-server-0.0.1-20190909.162347-1.war.sha1 
demo-server-0.0.1-20190909.162350-2.pom
demo-server-0.0.1-20190909.162350-2.pom.md5 
demo-server-0.0.1-20190909.162350-2.pom.sha1
```

Comment: Since yours is a Maven project, you may use `mvn deploy` with `-DuniqueVersion=false` as mentioned here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-deploy-plugin-2.6/examples/disabling-timestamps-suffix.html or by updating your `pom.xml` as here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7739898/8895640s. But as I have mentioned earlier, this will only be a temporary solution as support for non-unique versions have been removed.